# SceneExporter output bug?

Tags: three.js

In Three.js SceneExporter, when i export the whole scene, in the output json data i realized that textures are not exported correct. It produces Texture lines as

```
"Texture_3": { "url" : "undefined", ....
```

But there IS a texture. So i checked SceneExporters code there is

```
var output = [
    '\t' + LabelString( getTextureName( t ) ) + ': {',
'   "url"    : "' + t.sourceFile + '",',
'   "repeat" : ' + Vector2String( t.repeat ) + ',',
'   "offset" : ' + Vector2String( t.offset ) + ',',
'   "magFilter" : ' + NumConstantString( t.magFilter ) + ',',
'   "minFilter" : ' + NumConstantString( t.minFilter ) + ',',
'   "anisotropy" : ' + t.anisotropy,
'}'
];
```

The t parameter is map property of material which is THREE.Texture. But there is no "sourceFile" property or field in THREE.Texture. So what should it be? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

My own answer is below, changing SceneExporters Code corrected the output. I am not sure this is the official solution but i worked for me.

```
var output = [
    '\t' + LabelString( getTextureName( t ) ) + ': {',
'   "url"    : "' + t.image.src + '",',
'   "repeat" : ' + Vector2String( t.repeat ) + ',',
'   "offset" : ' + Vector2String( t.offset ) + ',',
'   "magFilter" : ' + NumConstantString( t.magFilter ) + ',',
'   "minFilter" : ' + NumConstantString( t.minFilter ) + ',',
'   "anisotropy" : ' + t.anisotropy,
'}' 
];
```